# jQuery loading animation without gif

Tags: jquery, plugins, animation, loading, gif

I'm looking for a jQuery plugin for loading animations without using a gif file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

loader on canvas - [here](http://jamund.com/canvas-loader/)

loader on SVG - [here](http://neteye.github.com/activity-indicator.html)